# Angle between vector as x approaches infinity

Tags: limits, vectors

Good day,

My mock exam has this question which has been bugging me and is the only question which I could not solve:

Let **A** and **B** be two non-zero constant vectors and $\vert B\vert$ = 2.

If $lim _{x\to \infty }$ ($\vert(Ax + B)\vert$ - $\vert(Ax)\vert$) = - $\frac {1} {5}$,

what is the value of $cos$ $\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between **A** and **B**

My approach:
sub **A** = (p ,q) and **B** = (r ,s) and try to get $cos \theta$ = $\frac {A\bullet B} {\vert A\vert\vert B\vert} $ which is $\frac {pr +rs} {4(p^2+q^2)}$

However, no matter how I try to manipulate the equation from the given limit, the pesky $x$ variable always gets in the way and I have no idea how to distil out $cos\theta$.

My understanding is that $\vert Ax + B\vert$ and $\vert Ax\vert$ will both approach $\infty$, so $\infty$ - $\infty$ = - $\frac {1} {5}$?

Any kind of help and/or hint will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "*So $\infty - \infty = -\frac{1}{5}$?*"  No... $\infty$ is not a number and so subtracting with it is invalid.  While you *can* talk about limits such as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n-b_n)$ this is not the same thing as talking about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n) - \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(b_n)$.  In the event that both limits existed and were finite in the second expression, then yes both expressions agree... but in the event one or both limits did not exist or were infinite then the expressions need not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can assume these vectors are both in $\Bbb R^2$.  Otherwise, we can consider the two-dimensional subspace they both reside in and just work with a basis for that plane.  Continuing where you left off, letting $A=(p,q)$ and $B=(r,s)$

So, $-\frac{1}{5}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(\|Ax+B\|-\|Ax\|) = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{(px+r)^2+(qx+s)^2} - \sqrt{(px)^2+(qx)^2})$

Recall that $m^2-n^2 = (m+n)(m-n)$. Rearrange to have $m-n = \frac{m^2-n^2}{m+n}$ and treat the radicals as $m$ and $n$ respectively.  The above expansion continues then as:

$=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{(px+r)^2+(qx+s)^2-((px)^2+(qx)^2)}{\sqrt{(px+r)^2+(qx+s)^2} + \sqrt{(px)^2+(qx)^2}}\right)$

Factor out an $x$ in the denominator and continue the algebraic manipulations to have it continue as:

$=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{2x((pr+qs)+\frac{1}{x}(r^2+ s^2))}{x\left(\sqrt{p^2+q^2+\frac{2}{x}(pxr+qxs)+\frac{1}{x^2}(r^2+s^2)} + \sqrt{p^2+q^2}\right)}\right)$

Cancelling the $x$ in numerator and denominator and letting $x\to\infty$ leaves us with several terms approaching zero, letting them be omitted.  We are now at:

$=\dfrac{pr+qs}{2\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}$

From here, you should be able to complete the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I managed to brute force my way through and noticed that some of your expansion and my expansion did not line up but I got the logic of the question and managed to arrive at the answer of   $\frac {-1} {10} $
Pulling out the x terms really made it much easier to work with!

Answer (score 1):

From the cosine theorem:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}|Ax+B|-|Ax|&=&\sqrt{|Ax|^2+|B|^2+2|Ax||B|\cos\theta}-\sqrt{|Ax|^2}\\&=&\frac{|Ax|^2+|B|^2+2|Ax||B|\cos\theta-|Ax|^2}{\sqrt{|Ax|^2+|B|^2+2|Ax||B|\cos\theta}+\sqrt{|Ax|^2}}\\&=&\frac{2|A||x||B|\left(\frac{|B|^2}{2|A||x||B|}+1\right)}{|A||x|\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2x^2}+2\frac{|B|\cos\theta}{|A||x|}}+1\right)}\end{array}$$

where the numerator (after cancelling $|Ax^2|$) is $\sim 2|A||x||B|\cos\theta$ and the denominator is $\sim 2|A||x|$ when $x\to+\infty$.Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{2|A||x||B|\cos\theta}{2|A||x|}=-\frac{1}{5}$$

which (after cancelling $|x|$) gives you $|B|\cos{\theta}=-\frac{1}{5}$, i.e. $\cos\theta=-\frac{1}{5|B|}=-\frac{1}{10}$.